# proper construction of a PHP html string inside of a foreach loop, not looping

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Using the code that I have below, I am getting the $cid to loop but the $html_string is not looping. It seems to only run once. Why?

**php**

```
  $query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT firstname, lastname, id FROM table_name");

add_action("wp_ajax_myphp", "myphp");   
add_action("wp_ajax_myphp", "myphp");
function myphp() {          
global $query;

$html_string = '';
foreach($a as $value){
 
$html_string = ['<div class=\"myclass\">'.$value-> firstname.'</div><div class=\"myclass\">'.$value-> lastname.'</div>'];
$cid[] = $value->id;
    }; 
    
    
echo json_encode(array('html' => $html_string, 'cid' => $cid));
    die;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
jQuery.ajax({
     data: {action: 'myphp'},
     type: 'post',
     url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
     dataType: 'JSON',
     success: function(data) {  
         console.log(data);
     }
});
```

**sample output from the above code:**

```
cid: Array(3) [ "44", "45", "46" ]
​html: (1) […]
​​
0: "<div class=\\\"myclass\\\">Bob</div><div class=\\\"myclass\\\">Smith</div>"
​​
length: 1
```

It iterates over the `cid` three times just as it should but only once

Comment: what is $a I can't find it in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$html_string isn't an array, so it contains the value of the last iteration.

Try

```
$html_string[] = '<div class=\"myclass\">'.$value-> firstname.'</div><div class=\"myclass\">'.$value-> lastname.'</div>';
```

and remove

```
$html_string = '';
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to do something like `array($html_string` ..... then? And if not then how do I solve so that it does become an array? It had been suggested to keep it as a string but I do need it to iterate over and over and then be displayable as the `(data)` in the AJAX

Comment: Just treat it like you do $cid.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille How do I handle the div that wraps myclass?<div class="wrap><div class="myclass">
firstname</div><div class="myclass">lastname</div></div>

Comment: I can't guess.  How do you handle it?  BTW, double quote is missing in <div class="wrap>.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Thanks for the reply. Looking at the answer, I know that $html_string[] is foreached and repeated.According to the answer, $html_string[] ='<div class=\"myclass\">'.$value-> firstname.'</div><div class=\"myclass\">'. $value-> lastname.'</div>'; I know it is reated.
How do I make a div that can wrap the value of $html_string[]?The desired final result is this.<div class="wrap"><div class="myclass">firstname</div><div class="myclass">lastname</div></div>

Comment: $html_string[] is an array, it may contain multiple lines. Read about PHP arrays or open a new question.